# How do I change a button image if my range slider = 0.5 ? (js)

Tags: jquery, image, audio, range

The basic idea I am looking for is:

```
if audio range = 1 then set myButton image "fullVolume.png"

if audio range = 0.5 then set myButton image "halfVolume.png"

if audio range = 0 then set myButton image "muteVolume.png"
```

I already have my range set up, all I am looking for is the code to make it change a picture at certain levels.
I have been searching for a very long time, if you could help that would be really great :)

This is what i am currently using for my range:

```
$('input[type=range]').on('input', function () {
    $(this).trigger('change');
});

var audio = document.getElementbyId("audio");
var volumeSlider = document.getElementbyId("volumeSlider");

function setVolume() {
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
audio.volume = document.getElementById("volumeSlider").value;

}
```

Comment: can you provide us with the code you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the event that triggers each time you drag the slider. And perform your desired action

```
    $("#slider").slider({
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.value);
        if (ui.value === 1) {
            $('#myButton').attr('src', 'fullVolume.png');
        }
        else if (ui.value === 0.5) {
            $('#myButton').attr('src', 'halfVolume.png');
        }            
        else if (ui.value === 0) {
            $('#myButton').attr('src', 'muteVolume.png');
        }
     }
    });
```

[Jquery UI Slider documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/)

Comment: thank you David, using this makes a broken picture symbol there instead, any ideas ?

Comment: Sounds like your path might be off, are the images located in the same folder as the scriptfile?

Comment: no so i used the slashes " 'src', 'images/icons/muteVolume.png'); "

Comment: Okey, If you have this folder structure:
-scripts.js
-images/icons/muteVolume.png
That path should be correct. But if images is stored in a folder above scripts.js, then u need to add ".../images"